# How to use both simple jwt token authentication and BasicAuthentication?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have an DRF api and I have implemented the simplejwt authentication system. It works well. It is usefull when I want to connect my api from external script (I don't need to store credential and just use the token).

However I also want to be able to use the DRF interface login when i reach my api from browser so I have implemented also the Basic and SessionAuthentication. Is it the good way to do that ?

in my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1), 
}
```

in my api views.py

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes, authentication_classes

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
#@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_all(request):
    
    # as a token is used, the user with this token is know in the requets
    user = request.user
    # show only mesures of user having the token provided
    mesures = Mesure.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
    serializer = MesureSerializer(mesures, many=True)
    
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

In my urls.py

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView

urlpatterns = [
    path('mesures/', views.get_all),
    path('mesure-add/', views.add_mesure),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='obtain_tokens'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='refresh_token'),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

As you can see I had to comment the @authentication_classes decorator to make it work for both with token and login. Do you believe this is a good way to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with this because as per the DRF documentation -

> Because we now have a set of permissions on the API, we need to authenticate our requests to it if we want to edit any snippets. **We haven't set up any authentication classes, so the defaults are currently applied, which are `SessionAuthentication` and `BasicAuthentication`.**

Source: [Authenticating with the API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#authenticating-with-the-api)

Ref: [Line 109: rest_framework/views.py](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L109) and [Line 40: rest_framework/settings.py](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/settings.py#L40)

Comment: thanks but my question was more about the fact that I am using both BasicAuthentication AND simplejwt .

Comment: It still works because you've extended the default classes while overriding them in your `settings.py`. In your case, by default, all three authentication classes will apply to the methods.